# positioning, make certain element occupy rest of the space in a parent div

Tags: html, css

I have the following issue I have a container div `.audiojs` with a width of 100%. Inside it there are several elements with fixed width, and one element with dynamic wide (`.scrubber` with width of 30%) The issue is that, no matter what percentage I try for `.scrubber` I can't get it to occupy rest of the container width in a way where it doesn't mess up layout on resize. Is there a way to make this work? How to force `.scrubber` (loading/progress bar) to occupy rest of the `.audiojs` width? without screwing up the layout and other element's with fixed width.

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w8GEK/3/

**HTML**

```
<div class="audiojs">
    <div class="play-pause"> 
    </div> 

    <div class="volume"> 
    </div> 

    <div class="time"> 
         <em class="played">00:00</em> 
    </div> 

    <div class="scrubber"> 
    </div> 

    <div class="time-2"> 
         <em class="duration">00:00</em> 
    </div> 

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.audiojs { 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 40px; 
    background: #404040; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-weight: 300; 
    font-size: 10px; 
}

.audiojs .play-pause, .audiojs .volume { 
    width: 45px; 
    height: 40px; 
    margin: 0px; 
    float: left; 
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #262626;
    border: 1px solid #232323;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #232323;
    border-radius: 2px; 
}

.audiojs .volume {
    margin-left: 12px;
} 

.audiojs .scrubber { 
    position: relative; 
    float: left; 
    width: 30%; 
    background: #232323; 
    height: 10px; 
    margin: 15px 12px; 
    overflow: hidden;
} 

.audiojs .time, time-2 { 
    float: left; 
    height: 40px; 
    line-height: 40px;   
    color: #ddd;  
}

.audiojs .time {
    margin-left: 12px;
} 

.audiojs .time em, .audiojs .time-2 em { 
    color: #f9f9f9; 
    font-style: normal; 
}
```

Comment: We would need to see your html and css to answer this.

Comment: @nFreeze oh my ;DD this is what happens after non stop coding, completely messed up, added it in!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What i would do is something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/GPvLB/1/

I positioned the `scrubber`absolute, and gave it both a `left` and a `right` position. These values would be the sum of the width (and margins / paddings) of the element that are next to the scrubber. This way the width of the scrubber becomes dynamic and will adapt to the width of the wrapper.

Something like this:

```
.audiojs .scrubber { 
    position: absolute; 
    background: #232323; 
    height: 10px; 
    left: 160px;
    right: 60px;
    top: 15px;
}
```

Note that I:
  - added position relative to the wrapper (to act as a reference for the position absolute)
  - floated your time-2 to the right

This should work fine in all browsers, and requires no Javascript...

Comment: There were extra brackets in css at jsfidle, removing those fixed everything up, and now works fine! thanks.

Comment: jsFiddle tends to do that... Worked fine for me in chrome however so that is probably why i didn't notice. I updated the jsfiddle and the link in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how you could do that: http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/wzgjy

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">

.audiojs {overflow: hidden;}
.fixed {width: 200px; height: 100px; background: #e7e7e7; float: left; margin-right: 10px;}
.fluid {overflow:hidden;}

</style>

</head>

<body>
<div class="audiojs">
    <div class="fixed"></div>
    <div class="fixed"></div>
    <div class="fixed"></div>
    <div class="fluid">Fluid div fluid div fluid div fluid div fluid div fluid div fluid div fluid div fluid div fluid div fluid div fluid div fluid div fluid div fluid div fluid div fluid div fluid div fluid div fluid div fluid div fluid div fluid div fluid div fluid div fluid div fluid div fluid div fluid div fluid div</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure if I implemented it correctly, but it doesn't seem to work http://jsfiddle.net/w8GEK/4/

Answer (score 0):

One solution to do what you want is using the `calc` value for `width`. Specifically

```
width: calc(100%-40px);
```

where `40px` is the total width of all of your fixed width siblings of the dynamic width.

[**View on JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/JJMZk/)

Note that this has limited IE support, as it [only works in IE9+](http://caniuse.com/calc)

Comment: Yehh, IE9+ is a drawback ;/ would like it to work at least in ie8